# Input bar border different colors

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to add certain properties to my input bar but the border is two different colors and I can not seem to fix it and keep the background image and other properties in the bar. I had tried changing only the border-top color but that does not work either.

HTML:

```
<input className="search" type="search" placeholder="Search for any wine"/>
```

css:

```
.search {
            display: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
            height: 40px;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 4px;
            padding-left: 45px;
            border-radius: 32px;
            background-image: url("https://www.vivino.com/packs/8c4e86902f36c8a519856195b1e4e8ad.svg");
            background-position-x: 16px;
            background-position-y: 50%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use

```
        border: 1px solid rgb(236, 236, 236);
```

You can override the values in the browser and your border now has the same color in all directions. So basically use `border` instead of `border-width` and `border-color`

[image]